# calling {{block type="core/template" template="custom/custom.phtml"}} stop working after 1.9.3.7

Tags: blocks

I called a .phtml block inside a CMS Block with command

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/home-slider.phtml"}}
```

and it has been working fine on Magento version 1.9.3.2. I upgraded core Magento to latest 1.9.3.7, now the custom .phtml block doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know why?  Thanks

Comment: Please add "core/template" in system >> permissions >>blocks and check